# Why is total amount of substance in a diffusion medium NOT constant if flux is zero

Tags: matlab, pde

I am trying to use this MATLAB code for 2D-Diffusion problem from the File Exchange [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38088-diffusion-in-1d-and-2d). The code is shared below.  All boundary conditions are set to zero (zero flux), and I set my initial condition for example as `u(20,25)=2`, and zero everywhere else. I run the code for about 100 time steps; I expected that at each time step the total field (amount of substance in my grid if you may) would add up to 2 (remain constant). But to my surprise, a plot of the sum of the u matrix over time decreases. [NB: I find the total field/value by `sum(sum(u))`].

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? or is my understanding of the concept is wrong.

```
 % Simulating the 2-D Diffusion equation by the Finite Difference
...Method 
% Numerical scheme used is a first order upwind in time and a second
...order central difference in space (Implicit and Explicit)
%%
%Specifying parameters
nx=200;                           %Number of steps in space(x)
ny=200;                           %Number of steps in space(y)       
nt=100;                           %Number of time steps 
dt=0.01;                         %Width of each time step
dx=2/(nx-1);                     %Width of space step(x)
dy=2/(ny-1);                     %Width of space step(y)
x=0:dx:2;                        %Range of x(0,2) and specifying the grid points
y=0:dy:2;                        %Range of y(0,2) and specifying the grid points
u=zeros(nx,ny);                  %Preallocating u
un=zeros(nx,ny);                 %Preallocating un
vis=0.1;                         %Diffusion coefficient/viscocity
UW=0;                            %x=0 Dirichlet B.C 
UE=0;                            %x=L Dirichlet B.C 
US=0;                            %y=0 Dirichlet B.C 
UN=0;                            %y=L Dirichlet B.C 
UnW=0;                           %x=0 Neumann B.C (du/dn=UnW)
UnE=0;                           %x=L Neumann B.C (du/dn=UnE)
UnS=0;                           %y=0 Neumann B.C (du/dn=UnS)
UnN=0;                           %y=L Neumann B.C (du/dn=UnN)
%%
%Initial Conditions

u(nx/2,ny/2)=2;




%%
%B.C vector
bc=zeros(nx-2,ny-2);
bc(1,:)=UW/dx^2; bc(nx-2,:)=UE/dx^2;  %Dirichlet B.Cs
bc(:,1)=US/dy^2; bc(:,ny-2)=UN/dy^2;  %Dirichlet B.Cs
%bc(1,:)=-UnW/dx; bc(nx-2,:)=UnE/dx;  %Neumann B.Cs
%bc(:,1)=-UnS/dy; bc(:,nx-2)=UnN/dy;  %Neumann B.Cs
%B.Cs at the corners:
bc(1,1)=UW/dx^2+US/dy^2; bc(nx-2,1)=UE/dx^2+US/dy^2;
bc(1,ny-2)=UW/dx^2+UN/dy^2; bc(nx-2,ny-2)=UE/dx^2+UN/dy^2;
bc=vis*dt*bc;
%Calculating the coefficient matrix for the implicit scheme
Ex=sparse(2:nx-2,1:nx-3,1,nx-2,nx-2);
Ax=Ex+Ex'-2*speye(nx-2);        %Dirichlet B.Cs
%Ax(1,1)=-1; Ax(nx-2,nx-2)=-1;  %Neumann B.Cs
Ey=sparse(2:ny-2,1:ny-3,1,ny-2,ny-2);
Ay=Ey+Ey'-2*speye(ny-2);        %Dirichlet B.Cs
%Ay(1,1)=-1; Ay(ny-2,ny-2)=-1;  %Neumann B.Cs
A=kron(Ay/dy^2,speye(nx-2))+kron(speye(ny-2),Ax/dx^2);
D=speye((nx-2)*(ny-2))-vis*dt*A;
%%
%Calculating the field variable for each time step
i=2:nx-1;
j=2:ny-1;


totalField=[];
totalField(1)=sum(sum(u));
for it=0:nt
    un=u;
    h=surf(x,y,u','EdgeColor','none');       %plotting the field variable
    shading interp
    axis ([0 2 0 2 0 2])
    title({['2-D Diffusion with {\nu} = ',num2str(vis)];['time (\itt) = ',num2str(it*dt)]})
    xlabel('Spatial co-ordinate (x) \rightarrow')
    ylabel('{\leftarrow} Spatial co-ordinate (y)')
    zlabel('Transport property profile (u) \rightarrow')
    drawnow; 
    refreshdata(h)
    
    %Uncomment as necessary
    %Implicit method:
    U=un;U(1,:)=[];U(end,:)=[];U(:,1)=[];U(:,end)=[];
    U=reshape(U+bc,[],1);
    U=D\U;
    U=reshape(U,nx-2,ny-2);
    u(2:nx-1,2:ny-1)=U;
    %Boundary conditions
    %Dirichlet:
    u(1,:)=UW;
    u(nx,:)=UE;
    u(:,1)=US;
    u(:,ny)=UN;
 
    
    totalField=[totalField sum(sum(u))];
    
end
plot(totalField)
```

[image: plot result of code]

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly. It is hard to know what you've done just by your description, actual code is always much less ambiguous.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks for the suggestion, I have included the code here.

Comment: Do you understand the code, or did you just run code you copied from the File Exchange? You should put some effort into understanding the code you're running, this is the way to learn! Run it line by line if you need to, to see what effect each statement has. You'll see how the code erases the values at the border to impose the boundary condition, so it certainly does not have a zero flux at the boundary, mass (or heat or whatever it is) is escaping at the edges.

Comment: By the way, `sum(sum(u))` is better written as `sum(u(:))` or `sum(u,"all")`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, to answer your question, yes I understand the code, and I did peruse it for quite some time before I decided to ask my question, I didn't just post it. I agree with you on the flux part, I noticed what is happening at the boundaries, I just wasn't confident in my thoughts, thanks for clarifying. 
I will like to add though,  different users may possess different levels of understanding of a subject; and that is fine; hence the forum. It doesn't mean they are not making an effort.

Comment: I didn’t mean anything by my question, it was an honest question to understand where you’re at. There’s nothing wrong with not knowing something, not understanding something or not being able to figure out what code does. We all start with zero knowledge when we’re born. I’m here to share what I’ve learned over my many decades. And I keep learning new things too.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  Got it! Thank you  for the help.
 I wish to modify the code to eliminate flux completely, so that mass (or substrate) remain constant in the domain throughout the simulation. Can you think of a way I way  I can achieve this? Thanks again

Comment: You need to add a mirror boundary condition -- material leaving is instead reflected back. At least this is what we call it in image processing. You can probably do that by modifying `D` in some way, but I don't know how.